# Can an unregistered account be converted to a registered account?

Tags: support, users, accounts, faq-proposed

A user can answer a question without registering.

When a person decides to register, can they convert their unregistered account to a registered one?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225) <sup>(not added to FAQ yet)</sup>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the user still has access to the cookie that was created for the unregistered profile, they can simply click the "complete signup" link or use the link that would have been emailed to them within ~24 hours with a completion link already available.

If the user lost that cookie, then the only way to "register" it is to register another account to the site and then [contact us](/contact) to have the registered and unregistered profiles merged together. It is not possible to use the recovery (forgot password) system to register an unregistered profile, as the recovery system explicitly looks for matching *credentials* which do not exist on an unregistered profile, because it is unregistered. (Previously, it used to look for the Email attached to the user itself, but since that field has been obsolete for years and will be removed soon-ish, it hasn't functioned that way for some time.)

Answer (score 8):

If you still have the browser cookies for the unregistered account than you still have access with it, you can simply register the user.

**The following method is no more supported, and it is obsolete**

<s>If you do not hold the browser cookie to your unregistered account, then you should recover your account. Just visit the login page and click `forgot?`  *(You must have provided an email address)*</s>

[image]

<s>After recovering the account, you should register it.</s>

**References**

- [How to register my unregistered account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42267/how-to-register-my-unregistered-account)

Comment: I kow that method but was looking for except that method.

Comment: @smileycreations15 Why? Does it fail (if so, how?)

Comment: This [other answer from a SO employee](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380082/4143855) seems to disagree with this, saying that it's not possible if the cookie is lost.

Comment: @Tas i think that my informations are obsolete. also the answer in the link that i mentioned is being deleted so i will delete my answer. But the OP must accept the other one before i do that

Comment: @Hadi there is no need to delete you can make it clear with a edit that shows that is obsolete.

Comment: I edited the answer.